# OData - Dont show record if collection inside record is empty

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, odata

I'm learning OData v8, using Entity Framework Core and .NET 6.

I'm playing about with expands and selects, think I have the basics down. Problems arise when the query gets a bit more complex...

We have:

```
public class car
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Picture> Pictures{ get; set; }
}

public class Picture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string url{ get; set; }
    public bool showImage { get; set; }
    public Car Car{ get; set; }
}
         
[AllowAnonymous]
[EnableQuery]
[HttpGet("Get")]
public ActionResult<IQueryable<Car>> Get()
{
   var cars = _context.car.AsQueryable();
   return Ok(cars);
}
```

Calling:

```
URL:/Get?$expand=Pictures($select=url;$filter=showImage eq true)
```

will expand images list & select only `url`, where `showImage eq true`

I came across Any/All and have been playing about with filtering but I just cant quite get it. I'm close and not sure if my implementation is the best but...

So below I used `Any()` to only return where primary image = true inside images

I have tried using another Any and an All but cant get it,....any help or advice would be appreciated please thank you for any help

Comment: Why do not filter in controller? `equipments = equipments.Where(e => e.Images.Any() && e.New_Price.Any())`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was populating the brackets in any(x => x.carName e.g) this was causing issues